# Similar function as attr() with parameter for callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button and an input box. When you click the button, it's suppose to make the input box readonly, before calling a callback function, but the problem is that the attr() in jQuery doesn't have a parameter for the callback function. Is there another jQuery function I can use that basically does the same thing but also have a parameter for the callback function, or is there another way to do this? Thank you.

```
<button> click me </button>
<input type = "text">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        });
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: attr() is a synchronous operation; you don't need a callback function. Just put your code on the next line.

Comment: There isn't anything asynchronous about `attr`, so just call your function after callng `attr`.

Comment: @MattBrowne What does synchronous mean?

Comment: @hobbs What does asynchronous mean?

Comment: @MattBrowne If synchronous means occurring at the same time, then yes, I do need a callback function. Since I need the function to execute only AFTER the input is set to readonly.

Comment: what do you want to happen after the input is set to read-only? you do not need a callback function because the `.attr()` function is going to block execution until is completed (i.e. non-asynchronous or synchronous).

Comment: @hobbs If synchronous means occurring at the same time, then yes, I do need a callback function. Since I need the function to execute only AFTER the input is set to readonly.

Comment: Try this like `$('button').click(function(){
 $('input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
 //attribute is set to readonly
 //doWhateverYouWant();
});`

Comment: No, synchronous means that one function will complete before the next one is executed.  It seems that this is what you want.  Callback functions are for **a**synchronous processes (which you do not want)

Comment: @jessica no. after you call `attr`, the attribute is set. Not some time later, right away before the next line of code is run.

Comment: @ochi Ah. Okay, so the next line won't run until the first line of code is executed if the first line of code is synchronous. And since attr() is synchronous, the next line of code will wait for it to finish executing, before running, and therefore there's no need to have a callback function. Wait, so does that mean ALL jQuery function's that doesn't have a parameter for a callback function is synchronous?

Comment: As far as I know, every asynchronous jQuery function has a parameter for a callback function. (Some functions, such as $.ajax, return a promise object which is an alternative pattern that you can optionally use instead of a regular callback...promises are a somewhat more advanced technique.)

Comment: More or less, yes... but it's not that simple.  All functions are executed one at a time.  There are certain functions that *could* block (freeze) your page/program because they take too long (or other reasons)... Those are better to execute asynchronously to prevent that.  When needing async functions, callbacks are executed at the return of those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() 
{
    $('button').click(function()
    {
        $('input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        // Do what you want here
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no attribute for that  you need just to remove the readonly attribute and you input will be on write/read mode :D , use this for that $("input").removeAttr("readonly");

Comment: @jessica: Prefer to use DOM properties instead: `$('input').prop('readonly', true);`, `$('input').prop('readonly', false);`

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah. That does look a lot better. Thanks.